# Questions on double dot product

Tags: calculus

Couldn’t get the concept of double dot product. Explanation and solution for the questions below will be much appreciated. Thank you.

1. $\nabla \cdot(S\cdot u)=(\nabla \cdot S)\cdot u+S∶(\nabla u)$
2. $[\nabla u-(\nabla u)^T]:\nabla v=(\nabla \times u)\cdot(\nabla\times v)$

[S is a second order tensor function, u and v are vector functions, $.^T$ = transpose]

Comment: As I commented on another recent question, $\nabla\cdot F$ isn’t a “real” dot product, but instead a useful mnemonic. Write $\operatorname{div}$ instead of $\nabla\cdot$ and see if that’s less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
\begin{align*}
\nabla \cdot(S\cdot u)
&= \nabla_i (S_{ij}u_j) 
 & \textrm{(Einstein summation convention)} \\
&= (\nabla_i S_{ij})u_j + S_{ij}\nabla_i u_j 
 & \textrm{(product rule)} \\
&=(\nabla \cdot S)\cdot u+S∶(\nabla u),
\end{align*}
where we define 
$(\nabla\cdot S)_j = \nabla_i S_{ij}$ and 
$A:B = A_{ij}B_{ij}$. 
I hope this method will help you to solve (2) yourself!

Comment: @EllisFan In tackling 2. this way, you'll need to rewrite the right-hand side with the identity $\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{ilm}=\delta_{jl}\delta_{km}-\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl}$.

Comment: @J.G.: Indeed, paired with $(\nabla\times u)_i = \epsilon_{ijk}\nabla_j u_k$ ...

Comment: The following might be helpful in this regard:  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/426497/26872, 
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/167761/26872